# Set layout variables for use by the (404) error pages in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

At present I set a couple of variables to be used by the app's overall layout.phtml, using the onDispatch method of a BaseController, which all my other controllers extend:

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) 
{

    $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
    $this->layout()->setVariable('platformName', $config['platform']['name']);
    $this->layout()->setVariable('platformYear', $config['platform']['year']);
}
```

This works fine, until I test some error pages and find that these pages do not get provided with the variables, as it's not using the base controller.

How can I get around this problem and provide the error pages with the same variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the event you're listening for.

In this case, I'd move this logic to the application bootstrap event or the application render event (I haven't tested this, but it would probably work fine).

One example, in your Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
    //$e->getViewModel()->setVariable();
}
```

Haven't tested that commented out line, but it should get you headed in the right direction.

EDIT: Found an example of using the render event

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $event = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $event->attach('render', function($e) {
        $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
        $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('test', 'test');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Necro)

When using `onDispatch` in a Controller, remember to return the parent with the event and all:

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // Your code
    return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```

Otherwise, the logic on your Actions in that Controller will be ignored.