# How to pass variables to the error view script in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: error-handling, zend-framework2, viewmodel, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

I catch the framework specific exceptions as follows:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    ...
    $sharedManager = $e->getApplication()
        ->getEventManager()
        ->getSharedManager();
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, 
        function ($e) use($sm) {
            if ($e->getParam('exception')) {
                $sm->get('Logger')
                    ->crit($e->getParam('exception'));
            }
            // trying to pass a variable
            $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('foo', 'bar');
        });
}
```

When I then try to access `$foo` in the `/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml` I get a `Notice: Undefined variable: foo`.

**How to pass a variable to the error view script and access it there?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the onBootstrap it passes the variable to the layout.

Try this:

```
$this->layout()->foo
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But is it also possible to pass a variable to the ViewModel of the view script? I'm asking, because I saw some examples, where it seems to work, e.g. in these accespted answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/18776447/2019043, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20800544/2019043.

Comment: Can't really find the part where they can access the variable directly.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Nevertheless, is it possible to do that?